# How to bind between ComboBox to all enum types within DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, enums

I want to display a framework UI element according to the bind type.
For enum types, I want to display ComboBox.

I already have this part in the xaml:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
   <StackPanel.Resources>

       <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" MethodName="GetValues">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                 <x:Type TypeName= <-- How to indicate for all enum types? --> >
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
       </ObjectDataProvider>

       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" />
       </DataTemplate>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Double}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0"/>
       </DataTemplate>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumValues}}"  SelectedValue="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0"/>
       </DataTemplate>

   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Is there a way to do it on xaml?

UPDATE:
Currently, I solved it using 2 converters.
The first returns a collection of strings from a given enum for the ItemsSource:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the given value into a collection of strings
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>collection of strings</returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<Enum> enumsCollection = value.GetType().GetEnumValues().Cast<Enum>();
            return enumsCollection.Select(enumValue => enumValue.ToString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The second converts an enum to string and vice versa for the SelectedValue:

```
public class EnumToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Last target type to be converted
        /// </summary>
        protected Type LastTargetType { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region IValueConverter Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a given value into a string representation
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>string</returns>
        public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                LastTargetType = value.GetType();
                return value.ToString();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts back a given value into an enum representation
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>enum</returns>
        public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Enum.Parse(LastTargetType, value.ToString());
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The ComboBox in XAML will be defined as follows:

```
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
                                        <ComboBox Name="EnumComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, Converter={StaticResource EnumValuesConv}, Mode=OneTime}"  SelectedValue="{Binding Content, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConv}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Focusable="False" Width="100" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0">
                                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem actually is.

Comment: What shall I write under "ObjectDataProvider" in order to support all enums, and not a specific one? Is it possible to do it in this way?

Comment: Definitely not possible. Not even in C# where also you have to explicitly specify the type.

Comment: Note that this solution will only work with one type of enum at a time. If you have multiple different enums bound to this, then the EnumToString.ConvertBack method will fail

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this please:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                        x:Key="AlignmentValues">
      <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="HorizontalAlignment" />
      </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
  </Window.Resources>
```

Btw google is your friend. Always ask google first before posting here.

I did that too before posting the answer and I found this link for you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613576.aspx

Comment: Hi, always read the question before posting an answer :) Anyway, your solution is intended for a specific enum type, and not for all enum types.

Comment: Sorry if I have not understood the question. The solution I provided you is from msdn, I copy pasted it. Its the standard. Its "that way" to do it. I havent made up anything. Check out the msdn I posted you

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you posted is a little flawed, in that it doesn't work well with different types of enums at the same time (i.e. you can't have two combo boxes bound to different enum types). By modifying it slightly I got to a simpler solution that works in all situations.

If, instead of converting the enum values to strings, you leave them as enums, then you can bind directly to `SelectedValue` without having to use another converter.

The xaml looks like this

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource EnumValuesConverter}, Mode=OneTime}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And this is the converter

```
public class EnumValuesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the given value into a collection of enum values
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>collection of strings</returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<Enum> enumsCollection = value.GetType().GetEnumValues().Cast<Enum>();
            return enumsCollection;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts back a given value. Not supported for this converter.
    /// </summary>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("EnumValuesConverter is a OneWay converter.");
    }

}
```

Of course, the names that appear here will be the ones you defined in your enum. If you want your names to be more user friendly, check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29495/Binding-and-Using-Friendly-Enums-in-WPF